# In a text file, how do I delete all lines subset of their immediately following line?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

In a text file, I need to delete lines that are exactly beginning like the next line. 
See example below.

Input:

```
I like
I like apples
I like apples and oranges
more
more everyday
more everyday
more everyday the more
more everyday the more I play
I
I like
```

Output:

```
I like apples and oranges
more everyday the more I play
I like
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It'd be better if you include what you've tried and exactly where you're facing an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $last unless /^\Q$last/; $last = $_;
             END { print $last }' input.txt
I like apples and oranges
more everyday the more I play
I like
```

Answer (score 1):

This [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) filter reads the next line and deletes the previous as long as it matches:

```
sed ':0;N;s/^\(.*\)\n\1/\1/;t0;P;D'
```

Comment: Just a little quicker!

Comment: Can you give me an example with input.txt. I can't seem to get it to delete anything, not sure if the way I input is wrong, it doesn't work on a mac, or it simply doesn't do what we want.

Comment: @proxsi - It works regardless whether you write `sed … input.txt` or `sed … <input.txt`. How did you _input_?

Comment: @Armali I did input just like you. It doesn't work on Mac OSX 10.15.3 Catalina. However it works great on Debian 8.  Thanks for checking.